# Incorrect syntax near ';' (after join statement-SQL)

Tags: sql

Brand new to SQL but I ran into an Incorrect syntax error while trying to perform a natural join. What am I missing?

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_LNAME, 
    INVOICE.INV_NUMBER, INVOICE.INV_DATE
FROM 
    CUSTOMER 
JOIN 
    INVOICE;
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the table definitions, so wew can see what columns we're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have to define the common attribute on which you want to apply the join

```
SELECT customer.cus_code,
       customer.cus_lname,
       invoice.inv_number,
       invoice.inv_date
FROM   customer
       JOIN invoice
           ON customer.id = invoice.id
```

*Here, I am assuming **id** as a common attribute*

For a full documentation, you can visit:https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score -2):

You are missing the `NATURAL` sentence. So, the SQL is like this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_LNAME, INVOICE.INV_NUMBER, INVOICE.INV_DATE
FROM CUSTOMER NATURAL JOIN INVOICE;
```

Comment: I added the natural and still received the error?

Comment: "NATURAL JOIN" seems database-specific and may still need the ON clause

Comment: Can you add more info